# R: How to extract all dates from a block of text

Tags: r, date

Does anybody know of a package that can be used to extract all dates from a block of text using R? I am looking for something similar to search_dates from dateparser.search in python (see pg 11 of this: [https://readthedocs.org/projects/dateparser/downloads/pdf/latest/#:~:text=dateparser.search.,or%20time%20and%20parse%20them.&text=text%20(str%7Cunicode)%20%E2%80%93,date%20and%2For%20time%20expressions.](https://readthedocs.org/projects/dateparser/downloads/pdf/latest/#:%7E:text=dateparser.search.,or%20time%20and%20parse%20them.&text=text%20(str%7Cunicode)%20%E2%80%93,date%20and%2For%20time%20expressions.))

I have tried searching google, but for R, I only find options to convert a character string (with no surplus characters) to a date string. I am more after something that can find and identify multiple dates in a range of different formats in a large block of text.

Comment: Extract the dates with, say, `stringr::str_extract_all()` then convert them with, say, `as.Date()`.  If you need more sophisticated parsing of the dates you find, `lubridate` is worth a look.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As I understand it though, I would have to write a regex for all possible forms that a date could take in order to use this (eg months written in full, in short, as an integer, with commas, etc). I was hoping for something a little simpler and less likely to miss formats that I personally do not see so often. The search_dates function has many possible formats already included, even for different languages.

Comment: Yep.  If you have numerous and unpredicatble dates, it's going to be laborious.  There's no such thing as a free lunch.